# Xamarin Android: build homescreen app widget with ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, xamarin, widget

cuttently I am trying to build simple Android widget using Xamarin. This widget should contain ListView, which is (as far as I know) the only element allowing to scroll widget vertically. I've been reading plenty of tutorials describing how to develop simple widget and I got no problems with creating widgets that do not need ListView. Unfortunately I need my widget to be scrollable vertically and I do not know where to start. I have not found not even one tutorial or example on the web showing how to create scrollable widget.

Maybe someone know where can I find tutorial or live example?

tl;dr: where can I find any materials showing how to create Xamarin Android that can be scrolled vertically?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Nailik/AppWidgetListView -  Good example for building simple widget with list view and scroll